# Covert UTC time format to local time

Tags: android, utc, android-date

I have a UTC time in this format `2013-03-04T14:37:15` How can I convert this into local time and then to `one minute ago` format.

I tried this first to convert the time to local format:

```
private String getDate(String date) {
        Date fDate = null;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {
            fDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return fDate.toString();
    }
```

But the above functions throws an exception saying unparseable date..

Comment: Similar to [Convert UTC to current locale time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049207/convert-utc-to-current-locale-time) and [Converting UTC dates to other timezones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088778/converting-utc-dates-to-other-timezones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parse exception you get is because of the extra `T` in your date(`2013-03-04T14:37:15`).

You can either remove that extra 'T' and parse the date with your current date format,

Or if you need to parse it with the `T`, change your format to parse the literal `T` as well,

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Works fine now am getting the formatted date like this: Mon Mar 04 20:07:15 GMT+05:30 2013, how can i change this to desired format like ex: yyyy-mm-dd 04:30 PM

Answer (score 3):

Check [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long%29) (one methods with the same name from DateUtils). It will be something like :

```
Date fDate = null;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
fDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(context, System.currentTimeMillis()-fDate.getTime())'
```