# How to convert and format a UTC datetime to local time

Tags: java, datetime

My program converts UTC time to localtime but not in the format that I want. I took an example from the following link [Convert UTC to current locale time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049207/convert-utc-to-current-locale-time)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-08-19 05:30:00.049 UTC+0000");
        System.out.println("**********myDate:" + myDate);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
**********myDate:Wed Aug 19 01:30:00 EDT 2015
```

**My expected output format is:**

```
2015-08-19 01:00:14
```

Please advise.

Comment: I recommend you to look for Joda Time Library...

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If you have Java 8 switch to `java.time`, but you'll still need to write your own formatter.

Comment: Why do you expect a time of "01:00:14"?  If you want EDT time, I would expect you want "01:30:00", to match the unformatted output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You parsed the text to a date successfully:

```
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-08-19 05:30:00.049 UTC+0000");
```

However, you then proceeded to print `myDate.toString()`.

```
System.out.println("**********myDate:" + myDate);
```

You won't get your expected format that way. Use (another) SimpleDateFormat to format `myDate` the way you want

```
final SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
System.out.println("**********myDate:" + ouputFormat.format(myDate));
```